# Unusual Transliteration Scheme

Tags: discussion, hebrew, transliteration, pronunciation

The Mi Yodeya user [MoriDoweedhYaa3qob](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2352/moridoweedhyaa3qob) uses an unusual system for writing Hebrew in a Western character set.  I do not think it is the [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). I cannot describe the whole system, but it differs from more common transliteration schemes in several ways.

- silent letters like alef and ayin (that may have been gutterals in ancient times) are marked with characters that are not from the 26 English letters
- J for Gimel instead of G
- W for Vav (Waw?) instead of V
- Q for Qof instead of K
- B for Bet/Vet even without a dagesh (unpredictable: Yaa3qob but Bavel?)
- TH for Tuf instead of T

My questions:

Does anyone else use this system or is this just a personal idiosyncrasy of his?

Does this system have a name?

I assume that this is supposed to make it more Arabic-looking and to preserve phonetic distinctions that Europeans have merged.  Is this based on modern Yemeni or Iraqi Hebrew?  Tiberian?  Second Temple period?

Are there any audio recordings that demonstrate someone trying to speak "Classical Hebrew" (voicing the Alefs and Ayins) or "Yemeni Hebrew" (making distinctions between the various gutterals)?

(This last one is a personal question to MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, don't answer if you don't want to)  Do you pronounce this way when getting an Aliyah (ex: Thoratho)?

I hope you realize I am curious, not trying to be disrespectful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i kinda of feel special that theres a question pertaining specifically to me lol.

in regards to numbers in my words: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_chat_alphabet#Comparison_table i use the numbers that people use when typing arabic with english letters. some letters in hebrew/arabic the english language doesnt have therefore the numbers took over. this applies to chinese as well when people right chinese with english letters. people use 3 for ayeen because it looks like the arabic letter for ayeen, and so on with regards to the other numbers.

i indeed use the 9anaa3nee teimonee pronunciation: http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/getimg.aspx?64271-14-700-0-3-256

there are other people using this type of typing if you search around rambam/teimonee groups on facebook and other social medias.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji5uc4Ly9sg this is an old video with bad quality but its a moree teaching little kids how to pronounce proper teimonee hebrew. if you want to listen to better stuff all you have to do is youtube or google aharom 3amram in hebrew. he pronounces pretty darn good in our times.

yes i do say torotho. i make distinction in the 3ayeen and the alaf and the khaf and the 7eit, and so does everyone else in my teimonee beith ha kannasath.

listening to a few peeyyu6eem from safaradeem, i have noticed that they pronounce the qof, reish, 3ayeen, 7eit, 6eith, wow just like the teimoneem. it is only modern safaradeem who dont do it anymore unless in a liturgical sense.

Comment: teimoneem use an old babylonian pronunciation scheme. if you listen to christians to still speak aramaic and syriac, they pronounce the same way as teimoneem. they say abuno dabeeshmayyo, lo, baroitho, mashee7o. i have heard them pronouncing this on youtube. however there was only the chaldeans i think that pronounced it as abuno dabeeshmayya, la, baraitha.

Comment: Most people who write Chinese in Latin characters use pinyin (or Wade-Giles for political reasons, or Princeton for some academics), none of which use numerals whatsoever.  The only oddity in Chinese Internet transliteration that I've seen is that pinyin `ü` becomes `v`.  What transliteration scheme of Chinese have you seen that uses numerals?!

Comment: ... or are you talking about tonal demarcation which are sometimes put at the end of syllables? (E.g., `ni3 hao3 ma?` instead of `nǐ hǎo ma?`)  I don't often see that in casual Chinese typing, but I guess if you wanted to be precise and not use diacritical marks, you can do that.  But those numerals aren't consonant or vowel sounds - they describe the tone for the whole syllable.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Chinese#Common_Phonetic_Spelling i assumed the numbers were the same as with arabic

Comment: Understandable, but it's actually just tone markings.  In Mandarin, `ma2` is the same as writing `má`, both of which mean, `"ma" with a rising tone`.

Comment: Just checking....your user-name (in Hebrew) is מורי דויד יעקב?

Comment: Yes(15.........)